# Join parent id to the table id?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a T-SQL query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    Products.Description
FROM table1
INNER JOIN Products ON table1.ProductId = Products.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Product as categories ON Products.ParentId = categories.ProductId
WHERE table1.notes IS NULL
GROUP By Products.Description
```

NOTE: These are not my actual table names.

`Products` looks something like this:

```
ProductId  ParentId   Description
1          null       Shoes
2          1          Flip flops
3          1          Gym Shoes
4          null       Shirts
5          4          Tank Top
```

and so on.

`table1` data:

```
table1Id   ProductId  notes
1          2          null
3          5          testing
5          3          note 123
```

My goal is to return a list of descriptions from `Products`, where their id is in table 1. This is dynamic and sometimes what would be returned could contain 10 parents and their children, and other times only 1 parent and the subsequent children would be returned. The key is to be able to get the parents, without the parents being in `table1`.

Right now I am just getting just the children, but no parent.

My expected result would look something like this:

```
Description
-----------
Shoes
Flip flops
Gym shoes
Shirts
Tank top
```

Comment: Updated! @DaleK

Comment: That can't be quite right because your expected results would be obtained by a simple `select description from table2`. Also none of your notes are null (`WHERE table1.notes IS NULL`) and finally you say "The key is to be able to get the parents, without the parents being in table1" but in your sample data, every row in table1 has a table2 id.

Comment: @DaleK sorry, when I put in the example data, I didn't write it out correctly. It should be fixed now. I also changed `table2` to `Product` to make it a little clearer and easier to understand

Comment: Closer, but with only 1 notes null you're not going to get 5 rows back are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Given its a single level Parent/Child you can do a simple `union all`.

```
declare @table1 table (table1id int, table2id int, notes nvarchar(max)); -- table1
declare @table2 table (table2id int, parentId int, [description] nvarchar(max)); -- Products

insert into @table1 (table1id, table2id, notes)
values (1, 1, null)
,(3, 5, 'testing')
,(5, 3, 'note 123');

insert into @table2 (table2id, parentId, [description]) 
values (1, null, 'Shoes')
,(2, 1, 'Flip Flops')
,(3, 1, 'Gym Shoes')
,(4, null, 'Shirts')
,(5, 4, 'Tank Top');

select T2.[description]
from @table1 T1
inner join @table2 T2 on T2.table2Id = T1.table2Id
where T1.notes is null
union all
select T2A.[description]
from @table1 T1
inner join @table2 T2 on T2.table2Id = T1.table2Id
inner join @table2 T2A on T2A.parentId = T2.table2Id
where T1.notes is null;
```

Returns:

```
description
-----------
Shoes
Flip Flops
Gym Shoes
```

PS: Note the data setup for future questions. Its makes it a lot more appealing for someone to answer when they don't have to setup the test data.